# Unable to inject dependency in Middleware in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am developing a web application using Laravel 5.2. I know Laravel supports dependency injection. I am doing it in middleware. But the dependency is not injected and the instance of the class that is injected is always null. This is what I have done.

This is my middleware

```
class StoreMiddleware
{
    private $categoryRepo;

    function __construct(CategoryRepo $categoryParam)
    {
        $categoryRepo = $categoryParam;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $categories = $this->categoryRepo->getTreeViewCategories();
        view()->share(['categories'=>$categories]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I declared in kernel like this

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        .
        .
        .
        'store' =>\App\Http\Middleware\StoreMiddleware::class
    ];
```

I config route like this

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'store'],function(){
    Route::get('home','HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
});
```

When I access home page, it is giving me this error

```
FatalThrowableError in StoreMiddleware.php line 20:
Call to a member function getTreeViewCategories() on null
```

As you can see, it is saying categoryRepo is null and it is not get injected.

This is my getTreeViewCategories() method inside CategoryRepo model.

```
function getTreeViewCategories()
    {
        $items = array();
        return $items;
    }
```

As you can see, I did nothing in model just to make sure injection is working or not. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the object property here:

```
function __construct(CategoryRepo $categoryParam)
{
    $categoryRepo = $categoryParam;
}
```

Change it to this:

```
function __construct(CategoryRepo $categoryParam)
{
    $this->categoryRepo = $categoryParam
}
```